# Cannot open a json file I am creating inside a function

Tags: python

I am trying to obtain a json file from this function, that is filled with items from the data variable. This variable data should then be dumped into the "hero_stats.json" file and I ought to open it for visualizing in the end. What is going wrong here? I can see all variables and names matching each others, am I missing some kind of call to open the file?

```
import pandas as pd, requests, json


# get updated info on game heroes

def get_hero_stats():
    data = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats").json()
    pd.DataFrame(data).to_json("hero_stats.json")
    with open('hero_stats.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)


get_hero_stats()
```

I get no errors from this, just a message in the end with

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: where is your return?

Comment: You write the data into the file **twice** (in `to_json` and in `json.dump`), but you never read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is returning `None`. You need to explicitly return a value, and assign it to something if you want to use it later.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


# get updated info on game heroes

def get_hero_stats():
    data = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats").json()
    pd.DataFrame(data).to_json("hero_stats.json")
    return data

data = get_hero_stats()
# Do stuff with data
```

Also there is no need to write the data twice, so I removed the second write operation...

Comment: Note that this isn't returning a file object, even though that  is somewhat implied by the phrasing of the question. This is giving the result as a native python list, which is probably what you really want, since I don't know what else someone might do with such a file except read the data out of it (so there isn't really a point to re-opening the file at all, just use the object that is already created).

Comment: Yeah, I see how this makes sense now. I should try to make a different program to open this file with the specific data I am interested in instead of just opening it at random.

Comment: @spool why do you need to save it to a file at all? The data returned by `requests.get` is well formatted and should be easy to work with directly. Really, I'd get rid of `get_hero_stats` entirely and just work with the list that gets returned by `requests.get`.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have another program which saves a list of json files in a folder and I thought I needed to save both files in there. This one in here is the hero stats "registry" table, the other files are relative to the games played with said heroes and would make up a "fact table". Would I be able to work with that fact table in the folder and using data = requests.get to work with the hero_stats "registry" table?

Comment: @spool If you have the data available there shouldn't be any problem working with it. The `data` object here is just a native python list of dictionaries, but you can convert it to a Pandas dataframe or whatever type you need. When you open the other data files (probably using `with open(file, 'r') as fin` and then `other_data = json.load(fin)` those should load as regular python objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

# get updated info on game heroes


def get_hero_stats():
    data = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats").json()
    pd.DataFrame(data).to_json("hero_stats.json")
    with open('hero_stats.json', 'r') as outfile:
        return outfile


get_hero_stats()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I realize now why the function wasn't working. Is it possible though that I should use the python environment directly rather than PyCharm for opening the file though? Because it still gives me the same message at the end and no file opens up. EDIT to mention that the file gets created, I double checked in the folder